# MySQL - Find and count duplicates (Quantities)

Tags: mysql, count, find, duplicates

I'm having some trouble with my shopping cart table. I've created a table that looks like this:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4f023)

My problem is that I want to be able to select the product id, and the count on how many times this product id is repeated in the table so I can display how many quantities of an item the user has in the cart.

Looking for an output result that looks like this:

> ```
> | user_id | product_id | num of prodcuts|
> -----------------------------------------
> |   12    |     43     |        3       |
> |   12    |     51     |        1       |
> |   21    |     39     |        2       |
> |   17    |     41     |        1       |
> ```

So I want to select `product_id` and also count it in a single query and I got no idea of how this is done so I'd really appreciate some help.

Comment: Several answers seem to be grouping by only product_id, so I added some more data to your example sqlfiddle where multiple users order the same product_id:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a6828/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select user_id, product_id, count(product_id) as num_of_prod 
from cart
group by user_id, product_id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4f023/12

Answer (score 1):

**Query :**

```
SELECT user_id,product_id,count(*) AS amount
FROM cart
GROUP BY product_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

To select all products and count how many there are REGARDLESS of the `cart_id` and the `user_id` you can use:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS num_products FROM cart GROUP BY user_id, product_id;
```

If you need something more specific or tailored, let me know.

Comment: You need to group by user_id AND product_id... what if 2 users ordered the same product id?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    user_id, 
    product_id, 
    count(*) AS 'num of prodcuts' 
FROM 
    cart 
GROUP BY 
    product_id, 
    user_id 
ORDER BY 
    user_id
```